# the Bitmap#createBitmap's original coordinate in android

Tags: android

[image]
[image]
anyone know how to clear the distance, I don's set any padding or margin params, but that's have a distance,check the images that I present, thank you very much!

I'm the new guy for this,forgive me!

Comment: maybe you can try to add this property in your `ImageView` of the XML. `android:scaleType="matrix"`. Previously I mentioned (which I had deleted later on) you can set the `height` and `width` to 0 dp but you will need to define the `top`, `bottom`, `start`, `end` constraints for the `ImageView` explicitly to do so.

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA thank you very much, when I set android:scaleType="matrix", it fixed!